# Docker Segmentation Fault Build on M1 Mac

Tags: python, docker, segmentation-fault, apple-m1, wine

I'm trying to get [pywine](https://github.com/webcomics/pywine) docker container to build/run on an M1 mac.

I get the following error

```sh
 => ERROR [4/6] RUN xvfb-run sh /tmp/helper/wine-init.sh                                                                                                        1.3s
------
 > [4/6] RUN xvfb-run sh /tmp/helper/wine-init.sh:
#9 1.095 wine: created the configuration directory '/opt/wineprefix'
#9 1.151 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
#9 1.156 Segmentation fault
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c xvfb-run sh /tmp/helper/wine-init.sh]: exit code: 139
```

It seems there are two issues with both the [image](https://github.com/webcomics/pywine/blob/93c34757aba5c9e11c4680d4a14cc6f1b8c52cb1/Dockerfile#L20):

`https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/python-${PYTHON_VERSION}-amd64.exe \`

(I.e. **amd-64**)

and the [base image](https://github.com/webcomics/wine-docker/blob/6f6ab2def958cd72635aaea921d38b8c5fbd8e7e/Dockerfile#L14):

`dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \`

(I.e. **i386**)

Is it possible to make this work? I've seen multiple [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774787/running-ruby-node-python-and-docker-on-the-new-apple-silicon-architecture) stating [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69189991/docker-running-linux-amd64-image-in-apple-m1-and-getting-qemu-uncaught-target) there are [compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814560/building-docker-amd64-images-on-mac-m1-chip) with docker x64 builds... seems like the only possible solution is UTM?